# How to most meaningfully use Angular error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

Lots of times when I am debugging in the browser, some mistake in my code will trigger an error in the angular.js file. Something like:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined       angular.js:11699

 at new <anonymous (bundle.js:1068)
 at Object.invoke (VM3011 angular.js:4219)
 at $get.extend.instance (VM3011 angular.js:8525)
 at VM3011 angular.js:7771
 at forEach (VM3011 angular.js:334)
 at nodeLinkFn (VM3011 angular.js:7770)
 at compositeLinkFn (VM3011 angular.js:7149)
 at nodeLinkFn (VM3011 angular.js:7795)
 at VM3011 angular.js:8030
 at processQueue (VM3011 angular.js:13292)
 (anonymous function)   @   VM3011 angular.js:11699
 $get   @   VM3011 angular.js:8628
 processQueue   @   VM3011 angular.js:13300
 (anonymous function)   @   VM3011 angular.js:13308
 $get.Scope.$eval   @   VM3011 angular.js:14547
 $get.Scope.$digest @   VM3011 angular.js:14363
 $get.Scope.$apply  @   VM3011 angular.js:14652
 done   @   VM3011 angular.js:9734
 completeRequest    @   VM3011 angular.js:9924
 requestLoaded  @   VM3011 angular.js:9865
```

Okay. So Angular is pissed off. Clicking on that line number will take me there in the angular.js file:

```
return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

I want to make the best use of all of this information. Instead of putting in a bunch of breakpoints everywhere and stepping through all of of the script, is there some way this can help me narrow down where the problem is? I mean, surely it wouldn't be being logged if it weren't useful to someone. But it just looks like gibberish to me. What's are my next steps.